# MySQL joins and creating a new table(?)

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way, so I'd appreciate a reality check.  Two tables; users and feed.

```
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+
| userid | firstname | lastname | username |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+
|     63 | Chris     | Smith    | csmith   |
|     65 | Roger     | Smith    | rsmith   |
|     66 | Diane     | Smith    | dsmith   |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+

+-----------+--------+-----------+----------------+
| messageid | userid | contactid | subject        |
+-----------+--------+-----------+----------------+
|         4 | 67     | 63        | Test message 1 |
|         5 | 67     | 63        | Test message 2 |
|         6 | 63     | 67        | Test message 3 |
|         7 | 63     | 67        | Test message 4 |
|         8 | 65     | 66        | Test message 5 |
|         9 | 65     | 66        | Test message 6 |
|        10 | 66     | 65        | Test message 7 |
|        11 | 66     | 65        | Test message 8 |
+-----------+--------+-----------+----------------+
```

When I produce messages on a user's page, I would need to present messages where they are in the userid (originator) or contactid (recipient).  The user's userid would be used.  BUT, I need the user's username to be shown, no their user ID.  So, this appears to be a join statement and I can put together a join that pull together almost all of this information.

```
select a.userid, b.username, a.contactid,
       a.subject, a.message, a.timestamp
from   feed as a,
       users as b
where a.userid=b.userid
```

Result:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------------------------------+
| userid | username | contactid | subject        | message                             |
+--------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------------------------------+
| 67     | Kimomaru | 63        | Test message 1 | This is a test, hello, hello, hello |
| 67     | Kimomaru | 63        | Test message 2 | This is a test, hello, hello, hello |
| 63     | csmith   | 67        | Test message 3 | This is a test, hello, hello, hello |
+--------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------------------------------+
```

However, I would like to add a column after contactid that would show the recipient's username, which would come from the username column in the user's table.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.userid, b.username, a.contactid, 
       c.username, a.subject, a.message, a.timestamp 
from feed as a, users as b , users as c
where a.userid=b.userid and a.contactid=c.userid
```

Comment: Oh, wow, it didn't occur to me to reference the same table a second time as c.  Thank you so much, I really appreciate it.